# CNN external window

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, pytorch

I'm developing a CNN application but I need to capture an external window for live pixel processing, I've looked at pywin32 but that doesn't seem to work for me. I just need to be pointed in a direction to accomplish this.

Comment: Check out the library ‘mss’. Also I would remove the pytorch/deep learning tags because this is more of a python application question